# Application of iterative algorithm $(\theta_n,w_n)$ converging to $\{(\theta,\theta):\theta \in \Bbb R\}$

Tags: numerical-algorithms, numerical-analysis, iteration

I have a iterative algorithm $(\theta_n,w_n)$ which I am showing converges to $\{(\theta,\theta):\theta \in \Bbb R\}$. 
The iterative algorithm is of the form :
$\theta_{n+1} = \theta_n + a(n)[h(\theta_n,w_n)]$,
$w_{n+1} = w_n + b(n)[g(\theta_n,w_n)]$

I want to know whether there could be any practical application of this.

Comment: At this level of generality, it is impossible to answer the question. What is your algorithm doing? What problem is it solving?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: I am showing that it converges to the 45 degree line. I am looking for a situation where these things will be useful.

Comment: Still too general. It's not even clear what you mean by "coupled iterative algorithm".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: There are two recursions $\theta_n$ and $w_n$.

Comment: @applied_math "The iteraive algorithm is of the form". Which form? Please include a specific example _in the question_.